# How do I detect image clicks in Dark GDK?

Tags: c++, dark-gdk

I am trying to determine if an image has been clicked, using the Dark GDK game engine. I've found no methods in the engine that do this.

I would rather not brute force this with a large nested if/else structure. I was thinking of setting up a container that takes an object which records the mouse position when clicked, as well as a bool value to determine if the image has already been clicked.

I apologize for not adding any example code here; I don't know how I would go about setting something like that up.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is detect the `mousex` and `mousey` position when it is clicked and then use something like the following:

```
if (xmouse > something AND xmouse < something_else) 
  AND (ymouse > whatever AND ymouse < whatever_else) 
THEN 
  pic_clicked = True
```

`something`, `something_else`, `whatever` and `whatever_else` would be the `x` and `y` `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` co-ordinates of the image.

This is just pseudo code and not GDK specific.

Comment: Although a good answer, OP specifically said they'd rather not brute force all images with `if .. else ..` statements. Maybe you can edit your answer to do the same using an array or with a container like OP suggested?